# Frustratingly Easy Domain Adaptation

Tags: machine-learning, domain-adaptation

I refer to the paper by called Frustratingly Easy Domain Adaptation (http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/docs/daume07easyadapt.pdf) where the feature space of both the source and target data are augmented and used as input to a standard learning algorithm. The code is just 10 lines but in perl. I want to port to python but don't understand what the input data looks like that must be processed.
http://hal3.name/easyadapt.pl.gz

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The input data are the files that you will read (those files will contain the lines of text).

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116254/cannot-understand-a-short-simple-algorithm-in-perl/34117210#34117210) for more details on the code: